# Infer rest parameters from first argument

Tags: typescript, types

I am unable of providing a solution creating the type that would infer the arguments of an `ErrorMessage` value based on the `code` argument.

`./errorCodes.ts`

```ts
export enum ErrorCodes {
  ErrorCode1,
  ErrorCode2,
  ErrorCode3
}
```

`./errorMessages.ts`

```ts
export const ErrorMessages = {
  [ErrorCodes.ErrorCode1]: (a1: string, a2: string) => `${a1} ${a2} message1...`,
  [ErrorCodes.ErrorCode2]: (a1: boolean) => `${a1} message2...`,
  [ErrorCodes.ErrorCode3]: `message3...`
}
```

`./formatMessage.ts`

```ts
import {ErrorCodes} from "./errorCodes"
import {ErrorMessages} from './errorMessages'


export const formatMessage = (
  code: ErrorCodes,
  ...args: Parameters<typeof ErrorMessages[typeof ErrorCodes[typeof code]]>
  // ^ Type '{ 0: (a1: string, a2: string) => string; 1: (a1: boolean) => string; 2: string; }' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.ts(2537)
) => {
  const message = ErrorMessages[code];
  const errorCode = `[${ErrorCodes[code]}]`;

  switch (typeof message) {
    case "string": {
      return [errorCode, message].join(" ");
    }
    case "function": {
      return [errorCode, message(...args)].join(" ");
      /**                              ^
       A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. ts(2556)
       */
    }
  }
```

I've tried the following line:

```ts
...args: Parameters<typeof ErrorMessages[typeof ErrorCodes[typeof code]]>
```

Even thought it semi-worked, there are some issues:

1. There's no intellisense when invoking the function.
2. as soon as I added `string` returns inside of `ErrorMessages`, the type was obviously broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would define the function:

```
export const formatMessage = <E extends ErrorCodes>(
  code: E,
  ...args: typeof ErrorMessages[E] extends infer Fn extends (...args: any) => any 
    ? Parameters<Fn> 
    : [typeof ErrorMessages[E]]
) => {
  const message = ErrorMessages[code];
  const errorCode = `[${ErrorCodes[code]}]`;

  switch (typeof message) {
    case "string": {
      return [errorCode, message].join(" ");
    }
    case "function": {
      return [errorCode, (message as (...args: any) => any)(...args)].join(" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Let's go over the changes.

- The function should be generic. Something like

  ```
  typeof ErrorMessages[typeof ErrorCodes[typeof code]]
  ```

  probably does not what you expect it to do. `typeof code` will **not** reference the type of `code` with which the function was called. It only references its static type which is `ErrorCodes`. The whole statement just producess a union of all cases.

  We should instead give `code` the generic type `E`. The type of `E` is determined by the caller and can be referenced in the the second parameter type.
- The second parameter has to use a conditional type to check if `typeof ErrorMessages[E]` is a function type before giving to to `Parameters`. As you already noticed, `string` can not be passed to this utility type because its not a function.
- The last error message

  `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter`

  can not be solved with some satisfying solution. The compiler does not have the means to *fully* understand the higher order implications of the type of `...args` and how it relates to the type of `message`. We have to help him out here by asserting that `message` is a function which can be called with whatever arguments.

  ```
  return [errorCode, (message as (...args: any) => any)(...args)].join(" ");
  ```

---

With all these things in place, the function can now be called like this:

```
formatMessage(ErrorCodes.ErrorCode1, "a", "b")
formatMessage(ErrorCodes.ErrorCode2, true)
formatMessage(ErrorCodes.ErrorCode3, "a")
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKJStAwhAE2AGc4BvAWACg5Ns9DgBGAGmtqxynyICY2adLj2ABmagF9q1UJFhwAxhETF4naAFkSxAIYBzEnAC85dnADa67o2IA6KyKYBdAFxwAFDqZvVUAJaIeixwOrw+MP6BAJTGAHxwAAYAJGReEnApoemo2vrMtgUJArSW9NZEdg6MvK4eXm4ARhAQADbAOogxRvHJqUzZuQa8BbZFZqXCNvZlIqK1CTnEugaiIwmS0lQy4NDwSirwAGbQqDowWkt5xnAAPBgIIDBIBKRVFbHuZkpEbhjFcCMdFA9MQ3DAAJ5gYAQQ5CTSDEiWJwPJ6IF5wAKHYBQOAAMUQKOepHcgOBoJCiHBXXiHXBcDMtAA-HAAApAnQ5J5QYg3fHxBlwNzmCFQmFwqAXZaIjBOJzUammQT7VRwRZS65WSV5Yjmb7AJwAbi+yhV2MmRGuCXMKTeiL1TgkTgSRq2gmIAHc-DAFAALDwi6GwtV5GKUQS0BQ6YjAOAAIl8AT0sbcYdoabgUGAMGQUAJ5jNDCIwWDBictgAVhAAu5Y3Goi701Jw4oozHY4dkIgFDA-Mpk4r07RM9ncxYC+VgMF3CWY1GPKSQW5aQrlySCkCQVEy5Xq7XY-WBU3aE2m9RjlBTucEe5bZUZoxWHGdLHgrGGvuzyczlqDDf7xVpnNYB+DgCJkGAKJPwvb9r1vQDCzEV9nyiIA)